# Where is usleep?

Tags: debian, ubuntu

I'm running JetPack 4.6.1 on a Jetson Nano, and a [PHP script](https://github.com/jdhawk/bcc950-remote-control/blob/master/index.php) that I'm trying to run complains about there not being a `usleep`:

```
sh: 1: usleep: not found
```

The answers to [Linux usleep: command not found, Why?](https://serverfault.com/q/140340/266901) suggest that it should be in `initscripts` (on RH) and [Debian is apparently the same](https://command-not-found.com/usleep). However, `initscripts` has been depreciated and replaced by `util-linux` (or `sysvinit-utils`). I installed `util-linux` but still can't find `usleep`.

Indeed, looking at the file lists of all three packages ([`initscripts`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/initscripts/filelist), [`util-linux`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/util-linux/filelist) and [`sysvinit-utils`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/sysvinit-utils/filelist)) does not reveal any `usleep` file.

This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1371352/399707) to [Is there usleep for Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/q/166066/399707), suggested installing BusyBox, which I did, but it didn't help. This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/308470/399707) to the same question potentially has a solution (buried within the `nosql` package), but before trying it, I'd rather just know where it *should* be, and why is it so difficult to locate? Has the command itself been deprecated?

Comment: I suspect the `usleep` command became irrelevant when the `sleep` command began accepting a real number argument, so the equivalent to `usleep 2000` is `sleep 0.002000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP could be updated to call `sleep` (of the GNU flavor)
with floating point seconds; `usleep` "sleeps some number of
microseconds" and there are a million of those in a second so given a
`$SleepStep` of 100000

```
$ echo 100000 1000000 / p | dc
.1000
```

that's equivalent to a `sleep 0.1` call. (The GNU `sleep`, not the other
kind that do not take floating point values.)

### Make usleep yourself

`usleep(1)` should not be too difficult to find the source for
and manually compile, or to write; the most
tricky part would be conversion of the input the user provides into a
`usleep(3)` call value, a hopefully positive 32-bit integer.

```
perl -MTime::HiRes=usleep -e 'usleep shift' 100000
```

But this has about a 30 millisecond overhead on my system so ideally you would want a compiled version of `usleep(1)`.

### Non-Standard

`usleep(1)` is otherwise not standard (non-linux systems, probably,
will not have it. They may not have GNU `sleep`, either, for that matter, or may instead call it `gsleep`.). A manual page indicates `usleep` was authored
by some folks at RedHat; RedHat might decide to simply stop supporting
it, and then who knows what various other linux vendors will do at
that point. This is where using tools specified by POSIX can help.

### Problems with Close-to-Zero Seconds in a Shell Script

Also sleeping for close-to-zero seconds in a shell script will become
problematic especially on slower, very busy, or systems with poor time
control (virts, perhaps). As the sleep delay approaches zero the
overhead of the fork/exec of the `usleep` (or a fractional `sleep` call)
will come to dominate the runtime. Brief sleeps would be far better
handled within a process with a `usleep(3)` or similar system call. This
will have *much* less overhead than forking out.

### Internalize the Call

So, in the PHP, one might instead call [usleep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) thusly:

```
exec ("v4l2-ctl -d {$Device} -c tilt_speed=1");
# TODO check for a v4l2-ctl non-zero exit here
usleep($SleepStep);
exec ("v4l2-ctl -d {$Device} -c tilt_speed=0");
```

this has two `system(3)` calls (what PHP calls `exec`) instead of one, but the portability of the sleep is improved.

Comment: I meant to mention in my question that I have actually ended up just calling `sleep` yes, and modifying the value to `0.1`... I was just curious as to what had happened to `usleep`.

Comment: two system calls instead of one isn't any worse here anyway, since that one system call calls a shell that calls then three programs. Honestly, doing this through system instead of the appropriate exec tools actually necessitates all this string replacement – and `system` in PHP is still one of the nr 1 sources of unexpected (uninvited!) remote code execution, so, I'm honestly not a fan of that script, even if it in itself doesn't seem to have a security problem I can spot right away.

Comment: FWIW, I have posted your answer as a potential solution to a bug: [usleep not available in ubuntu #1](https://github.com/jdhawk/bcc950-remote-control/issues/1)

Answer (score 1):

Part of your question seems to ask how to find a package with a utility command after some years have passed and the command may have been moved to another package (or there may have been several implementations and some are still available).  For Debian and Ubuntu, this kind of search is made easier by their package search websites.  I.e., https://packages.debian.org/ and https://packages.ubuntu.com/ respectively.

The customary upper search box named *Search package directories*, often won't help in this kind of search, but the lower search box named *Search the contents of packages* will.  Clicking the checkbox/radio-button for files whose names **end** in the keyword is the key.

On both the Debian and Ubuntu sites this search turned up the packages gnulib, epic4-help, scheme9, and lmbench as having files that might be useful to you.  Most likely lmbench - the others look like help text rather than executable code.

I don't know if distros with yum/rpm package repositories have similar search capabilities, but the Debian/Ubuntu ones have been very useful for
me on some occasions.

Comment: `yum whatprovides '*bin/usleep'` on pre-dnf redhat systems

Comment: Thank you @thrig

Comment: There is a package meant to directly solve this issue `apt-file search usleep`. Of course you need to install `apt-file` and update it.